# Create a single checkbox to enable a filter in ActiveAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have a scope for my model called `featured`. On that model's ActiveAdmin index page, I want to include a single checkbox filter in the sidebar to only show records included in that scope so, when checked, the page only shows featured records and, when unchecked, it disables that filter and shows all records. I've been unable to find a solution for this anywhere. Has anyone had any luck with this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

FYI Turns out it was easier to just define a scope on the ActiveAdmin page like `scope :featured`. It would be nice to be able to enable/disable a scope filter from the sidebar, but this works for now.